# SwiftyJSON API Request Returns Null

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I have some functions that are supposed to take data from the Wunderground API, and return a value from it. My class is below:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
typealias ServiceResponse = (JSON, NSError?) -> Void

class APITest: NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = APITest()

let baseURL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/91e65f0fbb35f122/history_20150811/q/OR/Portland.json"

func getRandomUser(onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {
    let route = baseURL
    makeHTTPGetRequest(route, onCompletion: { json, err in
        onCompletion(json as JSON)
    })
}

func makeHTTPGetRequest(path: String, onCompletion: ServiceResponse) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        let json:JSON = JSON(data: data)
        onCompletion(json, error)
    })
    task.resume()
}

func addData() {
    APITest.sharedInstance.getRandomUser { json in
        let historyData = json["response"]["history"]["date"]["pretty"]
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            println("Value:\(historyData)")
        })
    }
}
```

However, every time I run the code, it returns a null value. The API is in my code; refer to it as needed. Where did my code go wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to `printl()` your JSON data in the dataTask and see if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSON I get from this API, the `history` dictionary is not inside the `response` dictionary but at the same root level.

So your code should be like this:

```
let historyData = json["history"]["date"]["pretty"]
```